# How to Convert xml to List of Strings in jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am working on an `autocomplete` textbox.
I have a `xml file of all countries`. All is to `convert that file in list of string and bind to the textbox`.

But i am not not getting the values.

The xml is of format

```
<countries>
<country countryname="USA" />
....
</countries>
```

My code till now is

```
$(function(){
     var values = [];
                $.get('../../../Models/AllCountries.xml', {},function (xml) {
                    $('country', xml).each(function (i) {
                      var  countryName = $(this).find('countryName').text(); // it is returning a empty string
                        values.push(countryName);
                    });

                    //var oXML = $(xml).find('country'),
                    //    data = {};

                    //oXML.each(function () {
                    //    var countryName = $(this).attr('countryName');
                    //    values.push(countryName);
                    //});

                });

                $('#txtClientLocation').autocomplete({
                    source: values
                });
            });
```

any please help!!

Answer (score 0):

"find" is a function that returns array of DOM objects by given selector. See http://api.jquery.com/find/. There are javascript libraries to convert XML into JSON (e.g. http://goessner.net/download/prj/jsonxml/).

You could also use online converter (e.g. http://www.utilities-online.info/xmltojson/#.U845E7HEdoM) and simply put your XML to JSON manually and load the prepared source for jquery autocomplete.

But the best would be to use a web service and get the JSON by Ajax request (parse the XML on server side or put XML to Database and retrieve it better from DB).

Not sure what you intend to do with that list but your XML example doesn't seem to include the ID of country (or any key to identify each country differently than just with name).